# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'Users' of undefined

Tags: angular, primeng, angular8

I am getting this error message when i wanna display the label"Nom" of user class of Medecin data in the evenement component:

```
RROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'Users' of undefined
at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (EvenementComponent.html:34)
at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:36078)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:35061)
at callViewAction (core.js:35421)
at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:35378)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:35056)
at callViewAction (core.js:35421)
at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:35378)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:35056)
at callViewAction (core.js:35421)
```

Here's my code:

**evenement.component.html:**

```
<ng-template pTemplate="header">
      <tr>
          <th>Medecin</th>                   
      </tr>
 </ng-template> 

 <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-evenement >
       <tr [pSelectableRow]="rowData">   
            <td>{{evenement.Medecin.Users.Nom}}</td>                 
       </tr>
 </ng-template>
```

**evenement.component.ts:**

```
evenement: Evenement = new Evenement();
evenements: Evenement[] = [new Evenement()];
Users: User[];
Medecins: Medecin[];

constructor(private router: Router, private evenementService: EvenementService, private http: HttpClient, private messageService: MessageService) {

    this.evenementService.GetMedecins().subscribe(medecins => this.Medecins = medecins);

}
ngOnInit() {
    // console.log(this.evenements);
    this.evenementService.GetEvenements().subscribe(evenements => this.evenements = evenements);}
```

**Evenement.ts:**

```
export class Evenement {
constructor() {
    this.Medecin = new Medecin();
    this.Users = new User();
   }
Id: number;
Prix: number;
Medcin_Id: number;
Medecin: Medecin;
Users: User;}
```

**Medecin.ts:**

```
export class Medecin {
constructor() {
 this.Users = new User();

}
Id: number;
Users_Id: number;
Users: User;}
```

**User.ts:**

```
export class User {

Id: number;
Nom: string;
Prenom: string;   }
```

So, is there an implementation issue? Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: can you create stackblitz to replicate this issue

Comment: First, please respect good practices. Use camelCase for attributes (for instance `Id: number;` should be `id: number;`). Then, your `evenement` variable in initialized as empty, but never assigned with a new value. There must be an logical issue here....

Comment: Yeah the inconsistent naming conventions is really killing me here.

Answer (score 0):

you can use safe navigation operator `?.`

```
<td>{{evenement?.Medecin?.Users?.Nom}}</td>
```

Comment: Could you inspect the webpage, go into network and see how is the request body coming? Perhaps ignoring types wild guess, try  {{evenement['Medecin']['Users']['Nom']}}

Answer (score 0):

The error tells me for some reasons 'Users' collection is not defined ( does not have a value ), try to move the initilization code into ngOnInit for Environment class and see if that works.

If that does't work then have breakpoints or console logs into constructor of Medecin.ts, Evenement.ts and ngOnInit of evenement.component.ts. You will know why it is having a undefined value.

```
evenement: Evenement;
evenements: Evenement[];
Users: User[];
Medecins: Medecin[];

constructor(private router: Router, private evenementService: EvenementService, private http: HttpClient, private messageService: MessageService) {

    this.evenementService.GetMedecins().subscribe(medecins => this.Medecins = medecins);

}
ngOnInit() {
    // console.log(this.evenements);
    Evenement = new Evenement();
    Evenement[] = [new Evenement()];    
    this.evenementService.GetEvenements().subscribe(evenements => this.evenements = evenements);
}
```

Comment: for Evenement it say "Cannot assign to 'Evenement' because it is not a variable."